# need to assign variables some values in a loop in R

Tags: r

I need to assign variables some values in a loop

Eg:

```
abc_1<-  
abc_2<-
abc_3<-
.....
```

something like:

```
for(i in 1:20)
{
 paste("abc",i,sep="_")<-some calculated value
}
```

I have tried to use paste as above but it doesn't work.
How could this be done.Thanks

Comment: Or use `list2env` after placing the values in a list.

Comment: Don't name your variables like this. You'll be better off placing values in a list or vector.

Comment: @MrFlick: thanks a lot, thats a better way

Answer (score 2):

`assign()` and `paste0()` should help you.

for example:

```
object_names <- paste0("abc",1:20)

for (i in 1:20){
   assign(object_names[i],runif(40))
}
```

`assign()` takes the string in object_names and assigns the function in the second argument to each name. When you place a numeric vector inside of `paste0()` it gives back a character vector of concatenated values for each value in the numeric vector.

edit:

As Gregor says below, this is much better to do in a list because:

1. It will be faster.
2. When making a large number of things you probably want to do the same thing to each of them. `lapply()` is very good at this.

For example:

```
N <- 20
# create random numbers in list
abcs <- lapply(1:N,function(i) runif(40))
# multiply each vector in list by 10
abc.mult <- lapply(1:length(abcs), function(i) abcs[[i]] * 10)
```

Comment: Your 100% right, but the question asked for creating objects so I gave him an answer. `stuff <- lapply(1:length(N),runif(10))` would be much quicker.